# Haskell to Python: multiple-functions conversion issue

Tags: python, haskell, code-conversion

I am pretty new to programming and I was asked to convert 3 haskell functions into python as a practice exercise.
The 3 functions are connected, since output of one is used as the input of the next one and so on.

I get what the haskell functions do, but I have no idea how to start converting them!

This is the haskell code:

```
factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial n = product (down n)

product :: [Int] -> Int
product [] = 1
product (a:as) = a * product as

down :: Int -> [Int]
down 0 = []
down n = n : down (n-1)
```

And this was my try of converting it:

```
class function:
    def down(self):
        if self.n == 0:
            self.lista = []
        else:
            self.lista = range(self.n, 0, -1)

    def product(self):
        for x in self.lista:
            if x == []:
                self.product = 1
            if x != []:
                for i in self.lista:
                    self.product = i * self.product

    def factorial(self):
        self.n = int(raw_input("n="))

        self.fact = self.product(self.down(self.n))

        print self.fact
        raw_input()

c = function()
c.factorial()
```

Well, first I believe this isn't a 'direct conversion' of the haskell code. That would be okay though, but second, it doesn't work.

This lack of programming background is killing me...can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Edit:

The point of this issue is to exactly convert the haskell into python.
I did a stripped version of it myself, it was the next step in the exercise ^^

Comment: Converting code from one language you don't fully understand to another language you don't fully understand is a terrible way to learn programming. I would suggest to whoever is giving you exercises that they get you to the point of feeling comfortable reading and writing code in one language first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, ditch the `class` wrapper - that's not needed.

A straight Python translation would be something like:

```
# factorial :: Int -> Int
def factorial(n):
    return product(down(n))

# product :: [Int] -> Int
def product(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0: return 1
    a, ar = arr[0], arr[1:]
    return a * product(ar)

# down :: Int -> [Int]
def down(n):
    if n == 0: return []
    return [n] + down(n - 1)
```

But the recursive style is not very Pythonic here.  Next exercise: replace recursion with iteration, list comprehensions, or calls to `reduce` (if on Python2).

Comment: final exercise, read about the `factorial` function in the `math` module in the stdlib :D

Comment: Oh, I am amazed at how simply this could be! Had no idea haskell was so similar to python. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem with this code is not that it's unpythonic (i.e. not idiomatic Python), but that it gives the beginner a false impression of similarity between Python and Haskell. Python's lists are contiguous arrays, so getting the remaining members is an expensive operation for long lists. In other words, Python's `ar = arr[1:]` is quite different in terms of CPU and memory usage from Haskell's unpacking of first and remaining list elements.

Comment: Ugh, but now how do I make the variables pass from one function to another? This is my first time working with multiple functions, that's why I used the class wrapper ^^'

Comment: @EdwardCoelho Same way as they do in the Haskell source, they are given as parameters in the function calls. :)

Comment: @user4815162342 That's what I meant; recursively constructing a list is horribly unpythonic, as it is an approach that doesn't "get" Python.  But yes you are entirely correct. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write idiomatic Python, avoid recursion.

`down(n)` is spelled as `range(n, 0, -1)`. Use `xrange` if you want lazy semantics, which would be closer to the spirit of Haskell.

`product(lst)` is `reduce(operator.mul, lst, 1)`. (It would be more idiomatic to just spell out the loop, but this is shorter.)

From there on it should be obvious how to convert `factorial`.

Comment: Wow thanks! I really should be using lazy semantics and didn't know about that!

Comment: If you like lazy semantics, you'll love [generators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/). Python is lazier than people tend to think. :)

Comment: @EdwardCoelho You're welcome. If you found the answer useful, feel free to click the "accept" button. :)

Comment: I certainly did! I'm just trying to finishing the code. I always do that before accepting :p

Comment: Would you mind explaining the {reduce(operator.mul, lst, 1)} line a bit further please?

Comment: `operator.mul` is the [functional equvalent](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) of the multiplication operator. The `reduce` operation is equivalent to a loop of: `r = 1; for elem in lst: r *= elem`. Some functional languages call this operation `fold`.

Comment: If you like lazy semantics and to be able to use values more than once, you'll hate generators.